# Webservices in android

Tags: android, soap

I am  new to android. In my application I tried to call SOAP web services, in that I can't understand what is meant

for(SOAP_Action,OperationName,WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,SOAP_ADDRESS). The following is my full code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);

setContentView(textView);

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
OPERATION_NAME);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
System.out.println("subbu="+request);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS); 
try 
{ 
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
textView.setText(response.toString()); 
} 
catch (Exception exception) 
{ 
textView.setText(exception.toString());
}
}
}
```

Can anybody explain what thats purpose for. Give some link from which I can get idea.

Comment: First of all please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer! Second, your question isn't very clear. What exactly don't you understand.

Comment: Accept answers for ur previous question .. then i will help u with this question .

Comment: Hi THelpe,Mohit Sharma   Sorry guys,i am new to this stack overflow,so i didn't know these rules.Anyway in future i will accept.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP_ACTION / NAMESPACE and METHODS can be found in the WSDL file of the target webservice !

Here is a sample code to send a SOAP request to a webservice :

```
public class SoapRequest {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "xxx";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "xxx";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "xxx";
private static final String URL = "url of the webservice";

public static SoapObject soap() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

/* Here you can add properties to your requests */
    PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi1.name = "xxx";
    pi1.type = String.class;
    request.addProperty(pi1, "xxx");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true; 
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject soapResult = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    return soapResult;
}
```